# Adding Attributes of NFT metadata opensea in C# unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add some data to the attribute parameters of below code in C# but every time it gives me the NullObjectRefrence exception. If anyone know about it please.

```
 public class RootObject
{
    public string description;
    public string external_url;
    public string image;
    public string name;
    public Attribute[] attributes;

    
}

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Attribute
    {
    
        public string trait_type;
        public string value;
    
    }
```

In The updatethePlayerData() function below i am trying to add the values of trait_type and its corresponding value.

```
 public void updatethePlayerData()
{
     RootObject rootObject = new RootObject();
    rootObject.description = "aaa";
    rootObject.image = "bbb";
    rootObject.external_url = "ccc";
    rootObject.name = "dddd";
    rootObject.attributes[0].trait_type = "character_class";
    rootObject.attributes[0].value = "name of cahracter";
  
 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you have a reference for an Attribute array but the array is not created, you need a new Attribute [length];

Comment: @Everts can you explain a little bit, if possible write the code please.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution.

1. In the "RootObject" class changed the Attribute array to a list as follows:

```
public List <Attribute> attributes;
```

2. in the calling function create an object of the "Attribute" class as follows:

```
Attribute attribute = new Attribute();
```

Now I can assign values to the list as follows:

```
attribute.trait_type = "Some Value";
```

Hope this helps if someone looking around!